# Oracle - Inconsistent datatype error when checking for null Date

Tags: oracle, date

I'm trying to write a case for when a `Date` is null but I keep getting this error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

The code is pretty simple. Is there a different way to check for `null` when comparing to a `Date`?

```
case
    when cr.COMPLETED_DATE is null then '--'
    else cr.COMPLETED_DATE
  end completed_date,
```

Comment: Interesting, MySQL uses ORA-xxxxx codes for error messages? I thought that was Oracle only. What other connection is there between your question and Oracle Database (a different product from MySQL, even if from the same vendor)? I see the Oracle tag, is that on purpose or by accident?

Comment: `ORA-00932` shows its Oracle, better remove mysql tag

Comment: @praveen Oh I didnt notice it,the guy said mysql in question

Comment: My bad I work with both and got them mixed up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the issue is with the return values from the `case when` statement

```
cr.COMPLETED_DATE is null then '--'
```

returns `string datatype` and

```
else cr.COMPLETED_DATE
```

returns a `date datatype`, hence the error

> inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE

One work around is to change the datatype of second case condition to char

```
case
    when cr.COMPLETED_DATE is null then '--'
    else to_char(cr.COMPLETED_DATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
end completed_date,
```

or use a date like '`1900-01-01`' when the date is `null` like

```
case
    when cr.COMPLETED_DATE is null then Date '1900-01-01'
    else cr.COMPLETED_DATE
end completed_date,
```

Answer (score 0):

The two branches of your case expression get different data types. If the column is null you're providing a string, `'--'`. If it is not null then you are using the original date. That is what the error message is telling you.

If you want the null case to use a string then the not-null case also has to produce a string, so you'll have to convert your date to a string, using a suitable format model (don't rely on NLS settings), for example:

```
case
    when cr.COMPLETED_DATE is null then '--'
    else to_char(cr.COMPLETED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  end completed_date,
```

Quick demo with a CTE:

```
with cr (completed_date) as (
  select date '2016-09-23' from dual
  union all select null from dual
)
select
case
    when cr.COMPLETED_DATE is null then '--'
    else to_char(cr.COMPLETED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  end completed_date
from cr;

COMPLETED_
----------
2016-09-23
--
```

The result of the case expression is a string for both rows.

You could do the same thing with

```
nvl(to_char(cr.COMPLETED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), '--') completed_date,
```

but case is more portable and often clearer.